# How to install skype for linux alpha version in ubuntu 14.04 32 bit architecture

Tags: 64-bit, skype, 32-bit

There is no problem of installing skype for linux alpha version for 64-bit ubuntu, but there is no .deb packages have been released for 32bit

Comment: This seems to be correct, no 32 bit version available. Nothing we can do for you...